# Error Number: 42S22/1054 Unknown column 'kode_barang' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

> Error Number: 42S22/1054

Unknown column 'kode_barang' in 'where clause'

```
INSERT INTO `tb_barang_keluar` (`id_transaksi`, `tanggal_masuk`, `tanggal_keluar`, `kategori`, `nama_vendor`, `nama_barang`, `satuan`, `jumlah`, `departmen`) VALUES ('84797580073070', '01/11/2019', '26/11/2019', 'Power Supply', 'jfffksssssssssssssllllllllll', 'mmmmmmmmmmmmaaaaaaaaaaa', 'Pcs', '2', 'HRD')
```

> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/web_gudang/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Previously there was indeed a kode_barang column but it was deleted why was it still detected? please help me.

Comment: Can you also share your code?

Comment: which code ? sorry im very beginner.

Comment: are you sure that's your current query, I see no `where` clause in there

Comment: yes the error is in the display

Comment: Looks like you are studying wrong query. The `WHERE` clause is not likely to be the part of `INSERT INTO` statement.

Comment: so where do i fix it ?